# PHP - Login script not working correctly

Tags: php, cookies, administration, login-script

I have a question for you.
I am creating an administration panel, this is the first time for me, and I have some problems.

**1. Problem**
I am using mysqli_fetch_assoc() in this way:

```
    $row_cnt = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        printf('Result set has %d rows.<br />', $row_cnt);

    if ($row_cnt['COUNT(id)'] == 0) {
       return false;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
```

I use this to see if in the DB there are some entries, it returns 1 everytime, whatever thing I insert in the fields. I thought that it has to return 0 if there are no entry in the DB, am I wrong?

---

Please be patient, this is my first login page with admin panel.

Comment: Can you show the query you're using for the user ID check?

Comment: Make use of an Alias `SELECT COUNT(id) AS Counter FROM table_reg`. Then use `if ($row_cnt['Counter'] == 0)`

Comment: Tried but no luck. If I insert username and password that exist in the database, it returns to the login page. Instead if I insert an username and password that aren't in DB, I am redirect to the login page as usual, but I got this my personal debug message: Result set has 1 rows.
Your username or password was invalid

Comment: What is the SQL you are actually executing?

Comment: Mark you need to show more code, are you sure if ($row_cnt['COUNT(id)'] == 0) isn't actually giving an erro, $row_cnt is a number in the line above, and here its an array

Comment: Solved the error was mine in another file :P

Comment: You should post the solution as an answer and accept it. that way guture visitors may have use of this question as well. Adding "SOLVED" in the title is not how it's done on Stack Overflow so I'm going to remove it.

Comment: Sorry, I know but the problem wasn't in those lines of code, but in another file. I commented some lines to test and forgot to commented out.
So the login couldn't validate the username & password because it couldn't set them. Solved now.
Those two lines weren't written here, that's why I just added "SOLVED". Sorry about that.

`$_SESSION['username'] = trim(htmlentities($_POST['username']));
$_SESSION['password'] = trim($_POST['password']);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from taking a quick peek -

mysql_real_escape_string requires a connection to be established via mysql_connect, you need to use the mysqli_real_escape... function - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: Oh thank you. I modified in this way the statement, but unfortunately it doesn't fix my problem:
    `$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username); 
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);`

Comment: Ok, have you turned on error reporting? Put this at the top of your script "error_reporting(-1);" and re-run it. This will display all warnings, errors and messages.

Comment: I added that line everywhere, restarted XAMPP, but when I run the script nothing happen. No errors or warnings

Comment: I also check my php.ini and I have "error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT" and "display_errors = On" in it.

Comment: You need to run some debugging to find out where the script stops, errors or fails. Use the echo() function to output some text when the login script hits critical points, you'll see where to look by comparing the number of echo()'s you've added and what's outputted onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify what SQL you are actually using, but assuming it is something similar to

```
Select Count(*) from mytable where myvalue= 'Something'
```

The RowCount will always be one 1 as The Count will always be returned.